# Counting rows for some predefined data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I have a data set :

```
id label date
1  B     2014-02-15
1 NB     2014-02-16
1 B      2014-02-17
1 B      2014-02-18
```

I want to `count(id)` if for current `id` the previous `label` was `B`
e.g. i would like to have following output:

```
label count(id)
B     1
NB    1
```

So far I have tried the following query:

```
select a.label,count(a.id)
from test a
WHERE a.date <(select max(b.date) from test b
                where b.label= 'B'
                ) 
group by 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the previous label.  I would do this with a correlated subquery, and then do the aggregation:

```
select label, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.label
              from test t2
              where t2.date < t.date
              order by t2.date desc
              limit 1
             ) as prevlabel
      from test t
     ) t
where prevlabel = 'B'
group by label;
```